# How to exclude characters between certain characters from reg expression

Tags: php, regex

What I am trying to do is create a syntax highlighter.What I need help with is creating reg expression to find and highlight punction marks but I want the match to exclude strings between certain characters "",'' and also exclude strings that have been commented or defined//,/**/,#. I am currently useing this pattern

```
'/(!|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\-|&gt;|&lt;|\?|,|\.|\:|\;|\'|&amp;|\[|\]|\}|\{|~)(?=[^>]*(<|$))/'
```

This part seems to work to exclude stuff between tags but honestly it looks incorrect and I am clueless on how to structure the pattern correctly.

```
(?=[^>]*(<|$))
```

Here is my Highlight class

```
class SyntaxHighlight 
{
public static function process($s,$lang,$raw = false) 
{
    $orig_s = $s;

    $regexp = array(

          //Keywords working
        '/(?<!\w|\$|\%|\@|>)(and|or|xor|for|do|while|foreach|as|return|die|exit|if|then|else|
            elseif|new|delete|try|throw|catch|finally|class|function|string|
            array|object|resource|var|bool|boolean|int|integer|float|double|
            real|string|array|global|const|static|public|private|protected|
            published|extends|switch|true|false|null|void|this|self|struct|
            char|signed|unsigned|short|long|break|goto|static_cast|const_cast|
            LIMIT|ASC|DESC|ORDER|BY|SELECT|FROM|WHERE)(?!\w|=")/iux'
        => '<span class="K">$1</span>',

        //$var, %var, @var
        '/(?<!\w)(
            (\$|\%|\@)(\-&gt;|\w)+
        )(?!\w)/ix'
        => '<span class="V">$1</span>',

        // Numbers (also look for Hex)
        '/(?<!\w)(
            0x[\da-f]+|
            \d+
        )(?!\w)(?=[^"]*(<|"))/ix'
        => '<span class="N">$1</span>',

     //comments
    '/(\/\*.*?\*\/|
            \/\/.*?\n|
            \#.[^a-zA-Z0-9]+?\|
            \&lt;\!\-\-[\s\S]+\-\-\&gt;|
            (?<!\\\)\'(.*?)(?<!\\\)\'
        )/isx' 
    => '<span class="C">$1</span>',

    //char strings
     '/\'(.+?)\'(?=[^>]*(<|$))/'
    => "<span class='CS'>'$1'</span>",

    //back quote strings
     '/\`(.+?)\`(?=[^>]*(<|$))/'
    => "<span class='BS'>`$1`</span>",

     //strings
     '/&quot;(.+?)&quot;(?=[^>]*(<|$))/'
    => '<span class="S">"$1"</span>',

    //Punc
     '/(!|%|\^|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\-|&gt;|&lt;|\?|,|\.|\:|\;|\'|&amp;|\[|\]|\}|\{|~)(?=[^>]*(<|$))/'
    => '<span class="P">$1</span>',

    );

    $s = preg_replace( array_keys($regexp), array_values($regexp), $s);

     if($lang == "Text" || $lang == "Other")
     $s = $orig_s;

     if($raw == "false")
     $s = self::DisplayLineCount($s);

     return '<pre style = "background-color:white;margin:0auto;text-align:left;overflow:auto;">'.$s.'</pre>';
}

private static function DisplayLineCount($s)
{
    $i=1;
    $count = substr_count($s, "\n");

    $s = "<span style = 'color:#dfecf2;'>".$i."\t</span>".$s;

    while($i <= $count)
    {
        ++$i;
        $s = preg_replace("/[\n]/","<span style = 'color:#dfecf2;'>".$i."\t</span>",$s,1);
    }

    return $s;
}
}
```

I am getting the syntax to highligh from a database and calling the function like this.

```
if(isset($row['syntax']) && $row['syntax'] == $cat_ && isset($row['title']) && $row['title'] == $top_ && isset($row['id']) && $row['id'] == $id_)
{ 
    $id_ = isset($row['id']) ? $row['id'] : '';
    $top_ = isset($row['title']) ? $row['title'] : '';
    $top_ = htmlspecialchars($top_);
    $auth_ = isset($row['author']) ? $row['author'] : '';
    $date_ = isset($row['date']) ? $row['date'] : '';
    $post_ = isset($row['paste']) ? $row['paste'] : '';
    $newtext = htmlspecialchars($post_);
    echo SyntaxHighlight::process($newtext,$cat_,$raw);

}
```

I am very new to useing reg expression patterns so please forgive me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show your PHP usage, and provide example inputs, and expected outputs?

Comment: You should be using a regex [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), not `|` alternation.

Comment: This requires a big regex, want a really big regex ?

Comment: I edited my post to and added my Highlight class and how I am calling the function. I figured the regex is going to be pretty big it doesnt really matter how big it is.

Comment: Is this markup you are highlighting, or is it like php/ or c++ source code?

Comment: I was hopeing to make a universal Highlighter at this point it highlights most object-oriented languages fairly well and some markup.

Comment: Precedence looks ok. Observations: the comment regex won't cut it; all the quote-like stuff should be combined `" "` or `' '` or backtics; the directive is missing `'/(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*\#.*/'`

Comment: This might be a good comment parser `'/(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/|\/\/(?:[^\\\]|\\\\\n?)*?(?:\n|$))/'`

Comment: And this will find html tags if you need that. `'/<(?:(?:\/?\w+\s*\/?)|(?:\w+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:\'[\S\s]*?\'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*\/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>/'` Actually, I'd put html tags first in you're regex list as it could contain a lot of the other stuff - better to match this first !!

Comment: Try again for quotes `'/"[^"\\\]*(?:\\\[\S\s][^"\\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\\]*(?:\\\[\S\s][^\'\\\]*)*\'|\`[^\`\\\]*(?:\\\[\S\s][^\`\\\]*)*\`/'` using unrolled-loop. Good luck !!

Comment: One more note. I don't think the regex array will check each regex per single character position. If so, you have to combine all the parts into a single regex, and use a callback. What you'd do is wrap each part in a capture group (so you know which one matched) then, in the callback check which group matched, then return the appropriate highlight markup. To combine into a single regex, do it like this `/(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)|..|../` if you get my drift. For this you'd use `preg_replace_callback()` As a suggestion, get [RegexFormat](http://regexformat.com) parse and combine your regex's.

Comment: Thank you for all your help I'm going to go over everything and repy back in a while. Yes so each search will need to be wraped individually in the pattern with its own parameters. I thought I could just do (..|..|..) parameters for all